# Como salvar sessão do usuario pelo login ultilizando Java +AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs

Estava fazendo uma pesquisa de como salvar a sessão do usuario após ele estar logado no sistema, achei varios exemplos com cookies, porem estou ultilizando  java + angularjs, e nos exemplos que achei ele ultilizava o metodo doPost do jsp, onde recebia 2 parametros o response e o request, e atraves do response ele adicionava o cookie, como posso fazer para salvar a sessão do usuario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o **ngStorage**:

```
var meuApp = angular.module("meuApp", ["ngStorage"]);

meuApp.controller("LoginController", function($scope, $localStorage) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        $localStorage.usuario = "joao";
    }

    $scope.ola = function() {
        $scope.mensagem = "Olá " + $localStorage.usuario;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, qual framework mvc você esta utilizando?
Se for Spring é bem simples, veja o exemplo:

```
public String salvarUsuarioNaSessao(@RequestParam Usuario usuario, HttpSession session){
// Seta na session
session.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);

//Recupera da session
Usuario usuarioNaSession = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("usuario");
return null;
```

}